# How to detect if a word is repeated in a textbox

Tags: c#

I'm just trying to be able to detect if a word is stated more than 1 time in a textbox using a timer.

```
string obj1 = (string)this.webBrowser3.Document.InvokeScript("GetText", new string[0]);

if (obj1.Contains("HttpGet"))
{

}
```

I'm trying to make my textbox (obj1) detect if HttpGet is stated more than once, but idk how to do that.

Comment: you can use linq. `if (obj1.Split(' ').Count(t => t == "HttpGet") > 1)`

Comment: Unclaer: Are you looking for just this word or any duplicates?

Comment: You can utilize [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof) to perform two searches (using overload with `startIndex` parameter for second). If both are successful - you have more than 2 occurrence of said word. Another option is to compare `IndexOf` with result of `LastIndexOf`.

Answer (score 4):

A fast option that I can think of to count the number of words inside string:

```
obj1.Split(' ').Count(x => x == "HttpGet")
```

I am sure it can be done also with loops or Group by.

Comment: This is the most clean way to do it. And compared to regex probably slightly faster...

Comment: Won't detect the word if it's combined with another word, with a dash for example. Also, if there's a dot behind it (At the end of a sentence)?

Comment: Compared with regex it won't really recognize 'words'.

Answer (score 4):

Regex version:

```
int count = Regex.Matches(obj1, "HttpGet").Count;
```

Comment: thanks, this one works for me and is the easiest to understand